# Factors for sensitivity to electric shock

Tags: pain, senses

I'm frequently getting electric shocks in my office when touching things. I basically know why this happens and how to avoid it.

Still I started to wonder what would be the best way to touch something if you knew you will be shocked. I know that fingertips have more nerve endings but I guess they also have more callus. What are **factors for sensitivity to electric shock** and what **part of the hand is therefore the least unpleasant** to be shocked?

Comment: Practical advice: Take a metal thing (pen, key, etc.) in your hand and ground yourself over it. Then the current will flow through the metal and not hurt you.

Comment: I've built a lot of electric fence in my youth. If you **MUST** touch an electric fence, use the back of your hand, so if you get shocked you'll pull away instead of grab on. Also, a leather wallet makes a decent insulator to push down on a wire so you can step over. To this day I can't touch a wire without testing it first even if I know it's cold. Don't know if these tips apply to your job, I haven't seen an office building with electric fence.

Comment: @user137 the problem is static charge. Maybe it's the carpet or something. So it has nothing to do with touching things that actually carry an electric current.

Comment: @AndréStannek Can you put a humidifier in your office? The humidity will help dissipate static charges.

Comment: @user137 it's in the office of a customer so no big influence on anything there. To avoid long discussions in the comments I'd like to point out that this is not what my question is about. Of course I still appreciate your concern and help :-)

Comment: The dorsum of your hand is less sensitive than the palmar surface. It's hard to touch or pick up things with the dorsum of your hand, though.

Comment: I synced the title and body and made some additional changes to make the question more clear. Please feel free to roll back if it is not to your liking.

Comment: Inspired by [this study on bee sting pain](https://peerj.com/articles/338/), you could do your own study involving electric shock. [This piezo electric lighter](http://www.amazon.com/Maverick-Bl-02-Piezo-Electric-Igniter/dp/B0012RRG8O/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1421798680&sr=8-2&keywords=Piezo+Electric+Lighter) claims to deliver 10,000V shocks at safe currents, and if you do the experiments on just yourself you usually don't need approval for human subjects.

Comment: @ChrisStronks I changed the title again because that's the part of the question I'd like to emphasize. Otherwise your edit is fine, thanks!

Comment: @user137 that would answer the second part of my question. Still I'd like to know the reasons. Does it only rely on the number of nerves or are there other factors? See my last comment for the emphases of my question.

Comment: @AndréStannek This may be a nobody knows (for now) question. I would certainly be curious if there is research on this and more so why said research was carried out! Who would fund this? The only electric-pain experiment that springs to mind is the (in)famous Milgram experiment. This still doesn't even begin to answer your question.